# How do I access objects in user namespace with jupyter_client?

Tags: python, zeromq, jupyter

I want to execute cells in an IPython / Jupyer notebook programmatically and do some introspection on them, like getting user variables.

With IPython.core.InteractiveShell it is quite easy:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
shell = InteractiveShell()
shell.run_cell("foo = 1")
assert shell.ns_table['user_local']['foo'] == 1
```

I cannot user InteractiveShell though because I want to capture rich output ([as discussed in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143643/ipython-interactiveshell-fails-to-yield-rich-output-when-using-matplotlib-inli)). In order to do that, I have to use [jupyter_client](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/tree/master/jupyter_client) which uses a ZeroMQ connection to the kernel.

My question is, how can I retrieve object from the namespace of an IPython kernel, the way ns_table does in the above example? Is some kind of boilerplate code injection into cell source and/or pickling/unpickling of user expressions unavoidable ([as discussed in yet another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222141/getting-output-from-jupyter-kernel-in-ipython-script))?